# 3 way interaction in linear mixed model with 2 continous and 1 categorical predictors

Tags: mixed-model, interaction, post-hoc, contrasts, lsmeans

I want to know if the relationship between x (continuous independent variable) and y (continuous dependent variable) is influenced by gender (binary variable) AND stronger for those participants who have high values in y (the dependent variable).

For this reason, I split my participants into three equal-sized groups:

```
dt$split <- as.numeric(cut_number(dt$y, 3))
dt$split <- dt$split - 1
```

Then I built a linear mixed model like this:

```
model <- lmer(y ~ split * x * gender + (1 | study), data = dt)
```

I have a significant interaction term between the `split:x:gender`.
(In the output of `summary(model)` as well as in the output of `joint_tests(model)` of the **emmeans** package).

How can I test if there is a significant interaction between gender and x in the upper level of my model, i.e., for those participants who have a split value of 2 (even though the split is treated as a numerical variable)? (I want to know if gender influences the relationship between x and y for participants with a split-value = 2).

Is this approach correct?

```
emtrends(model, specs = pairwise ~ gender | split, var = "x", 
         at = list(split = 2))
```